# Support HTTP CONNECT Tunnel in local development with Google App Engine and python-request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

GAE doesn't support `HTTP CONNECT Tunnelling`. It makes sense on the production server. However, locally I really need this feature because I'm running my own proxy server (Squid3) to tunnel through my school's. To enable `HTTP Connect Tunnelling`, I replaced `httplib.py` in gae's Python runtime with default `httplib` so that `set_tunnel` is implemented. This doesn't work with [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) though. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/path_to_my_project/requests/packages/urllib3/util.py", line 520, in resolve_cert_reqs
  res = getattr(ssl, 'CERT_' + candidate)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CERT_CERT_REQUIRED'
```

Here is the function that produces the error:

```
def resolve_cert_reqs(candidate):
    """ 
    Resolves the argument to a numeric constant, which can be passed to
    the wrap_socket function/method from the ssl module.
    Defaults to :data:`ssl.CERT_NONE`.
    If given a string it is assumed to be the name of the constant in the
    :mod:`ssl` module or its abbrevation.
    (So you can specify `REQUIRED` instead of `CERT_REQUIRED`.
    If it's neither `None` nor a string we assume it is already the numeric
    constant which can directly be passed to wrap_socket.
    """
    if candidate is None:
        return CERT_NONE

    if isinstance(candidate, str):
        res = getattr(ssl, candidate, None)
        if res is None:
            res = getattr(ssl, candidate)
        return res 

    return candidate
```

So I tried to inspect the `ssl` module and this is what I get:

```
{'__doc__': None, '__loader__': , '__name__': 'ssl', '__package__': None}
```

which is very weird because normal `ssl` module looks like this

```
{'CERT_NONE': 0,
 'CERT_OPTIONAL': 1,
 'CERT_REQUIRED': 2,
 'DER_cert_to_PEM_cert': <function DER_cert_to_PEM_cert at 0x7f6df6ab4938>,
 'OPENSSL_VERSION': 'OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012',
 'OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO': (1, 0, 1, 0, 15),
 'OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER': 268439567L,
 'PEM_FOOTER': '-----END CERTIFICATE-----',
 'PEM_HEADER': '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----',
 'PEM_cert_to_DER_cert': <function PEM_cert_to_DER_cert at 0x7f6df6ab49b0>,
 'PROTOCOL_SSLv23': 2,
 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3': 1,
 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1': 3,
 'RAND_add': <built-in function RAND_add>,
 'RAND_egd': <built-in function RAND_egd>,
 'RAND_status': <built-in function RAND_status>,
 'SSLError': <class 'ssl.SSLError'>,
 'SSLSocket': <class 'ssl.SSLSocket'>,
 'SSL_ERROR_EOF': 8,
 'SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE': 9,
 'SSL_ERROR_SSL': 1,
 'SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL': 5,
 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT': 7,
 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ': 2,
 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE': 3,
 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP': 4,
 'SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN': 6,
 '_DEFAULT_CIPHERS': 'DEFAULT:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXPORT:!SSLv2',
 '_PROTOCOL_NAMES': {1: 'SSLv3', 2: 'SSLv23', 3: 'TLSv1'},
 '_SSLv2_IF_EXISTS': None,
 ...
 }
```

among other things. So I tried to drop in a local version of `ssl.py` because apparently GAE runtime doesn't provide this module AND WAS ABLE TO PROCEED ... to the next error.

```
  File "/path_to_my_project/requests/packages/urllib3/ssl.py", line 139, in __init__
    ciphers)
TypeError: must be _socket.socket, not socket
```

This error corresponds to the `SSLSocket` class:

```
from socket import socket
class SSLSocket(socket):
   ...
```

So I changed it into:

```
from _socket import socket
```

which works and brings me to the next error:

```
File "/path_to_gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1589, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 800, in <module>
    class HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'
```

I google'd again and found out that if python is installed before libssl-dev, this won't work. So I recompiled Python and all that, which got me to the next error

```
  File "/path_to_my_project/requests/adapters.py", line 363, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

which doesn't make any sense because I do have `ssl.py` installed.

Please help!!! I'll give all my reputation to the one who could help me get this running.

Comment: Well, firstly, dropping `ssl.py` into the Python runtime won't work. `ssl.py` relies on the `_ssl` module, which is actually a C extension build at the time you compile Python, and linked against OpenSSL. Make sure you compile Python with SSL support.

Comment: It's additionally worth noting that things like this are why Requests doesn't support GAE. It might work, but it might not.

Comment: @Lukasa I did wipe out python and recompile it with SSL support. If droppoing `ssl.py` into the run time won't work, can you recommend some alternatives?

Comment: Unfortunately, SSL in Python is not totally trivial. I don't know of anything off the top of my head, especially if you did compile with OpenSSL installed.